# Closing An SqlDataReader that might not have been initialized

Tags: c#, exception

I'm stuck in a cycle of different compiler errors and I need some assistance.

So case 1: SqlDataReader executed outside of try block allows closing it later, however, leaves the reader exceptions unhanded.

```
var cmd = String.Format("SQL COMMAND HERE");
var command = new SqlCommand(cmd, conSQL);
SqlDataReader readerSql = command.ExecuteReader();  //Unhandled Exceptions here
try
{
    while (readerSql.Read())
    {....}
}
catch (SqlException e)
{...}
finally
{
    readerSql.Close(); //Compiler error: Might not have been initialized          
}
```

Case 2: Reader is executed inside try block, reader exceptions can be handled, however, reader cannot be closed on exceptions.

```
SqlDataReader readerSql;
try{
    readerSql = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (readerSql.Read())
    {...}
    readerSql.Close(); //Does not close on exceptions
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    readerSql.Close(); //Compiler error: Might not have been initialized
}
finally
{
    if(readerSql != null)  //Compiler Error on if statement, same as below
        readerSql.Close(); //Compiler error: Might not have been initialized    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, it solves your issue:

The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

Comment: Beat me to it! @Zero this is your answer

Answer (score 1):

As Alioza says the best method is the using statement.

```
using (var readerSql  = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (readerSql.Read()) {
        {....}
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx (using statement documentation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `using` statement and not worry about closing.

```
using(SqlDataReader readerSql = command.ExecuteReader()){
     try{
            while (readerSql.Read())
            {....}
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
           //execption
        }
}
```